# How to turn off notification of email content?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

When I miss a call, I get a voicemail. I receive 3 notifications. A notification of the missed call itself,a notification of the email, and a notification of *contents* inside the body of the email. I want to turn off the notification which shows the *Content* of the mail.

Device : Samsung Galaxy S4

Answer (score 0):

Open your settings, go into Apps, find Gmail in the list and uncheck 'Show notifications'.
That's all!